# Starting new activity after facebook login success

Tags: java, android, facebook

I have been trying to start a new activity from a successful login attempt with facebook integration however when the login button is pressed after logging pin it returns to the same activity that the login button is on.

I already have in place an intent to move to the next activity however it doesn't seem to have any response to success of the login.

Here is my code (sorry for the untidiness I've been at this for a long time now):

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.login.Login;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import org.json.JSONObject;


    public class userlogin extends FragmentActivity {

        LoginButton loginButton; //The Facebook login button
        TextView loginstatus;
        CallbackManager callbackManager;
        private AccessToken accessToken;


        @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_userlogin);
                loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
                loginstatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.loginstatus);
                callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
                loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        // **Description: If the user cancels the login before it is completed a message will
        //                be shown to let them know that they are not logged in
        //**Parameters:
        //** Loginresult: the results of the login attempt.
        //**
        //**Precondition: loginButton must have been clicked first
        //**
        //**throws: N/A
        //** returns: a textView that displays a message of whether or not the login was succesful

            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            loginstatus.setText("Login Success");
            accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();

            Toast.makeText(userlogin.this, "Eureka", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {


                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    Log.d("FB", "complete");
                    Log.d("FB", object.optString("name"));
                    Log.d("FB", object.optString("link"));
                    Log.d("FB", object.optString("id"));
                    Log.d("FB", object.optString("gender"));
                    TextView Username;
                    Username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginstatus);
                    String id = object.optString("id");
                    String name = object.optString("name");
                    Username.setText("Welcome:" + name);
                    ImageView userPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.facebookuserPortrait);
                    String i = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large";
                    Glide.with(userlogin.this).load(i).override(350, 350).into(userPhoto);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(userlogin.this, AlertsandPlanning.class);
                        startActivity(intent);


                }

                // **Description: If the user cancels the login before it is completed a message will
                //                be shown to let them know that they are not logged in
                //**Parameters: N/A
                //**
                //**Precondition: loginButton must have been clicked first
                //**
                //**throws: N/A
                //** returns: a textView that displays a message
                public void onCancel() {
                    loginstatus.setText("Login Canceled");
                }

                // **Description: If the user has an error during the login before it is completed
                //                a message will be shown to let them know that they are not logged in
                //**Parameters: FacebookException: an error transpoding if the login fails
                //**
                //**Precondition: loginButton must have been clicked first
                //**
                //**throws: Exception
                //** returns: a textView that displays a message
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    loginstatus.setText("Something went wrong \n+" +
                            "Check your credentials and try again");

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }

        protected void onActivivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            userlogin.super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }


    });
}
```

}

I appreciate any insight given, I may start from scratch on this activity and try again if nothing seems to work.

To reiterate the issue: The "Continue with facebook" button is clicked and the next activity shown is the userlogin activity instead of the AlertsandPlanning activity.

update:

I tried the current first comment here is the updated code,

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import android.view.View;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphRequestAsyncTask;
    public class UserLogin extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

LoginButton btnFacebookLogin;
CallbackManager callbackManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_login);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    setUI();
}

private void setUI() {


    btnFacebookLogin = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.FBLoginBtn);

    btnFacebookLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnFacebookLogin.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.FBLoginBtn:
            facebookLogin();
    }
}

private void facebookLogin() {
    // Callback registration
    btnFacebookLogin.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
```

// App code

```
            final AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            GraphRequestAsyncTask request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                    String username = (user.optString("name"));
                }
            }).executeAsync();


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Success with facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent startAlertsAndPlanning = new Intent(UserLogin.this, AlertsAndPlanning.class);
            startActivity(startAlertsAndPlanning);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
        }
    });

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

Comment: Are you facing any error's ?..if yes please post those logs here that will help to solve the problem and analyze it properly.

Comment: No errors were encountered with the above code, before posting I had a few errors but they were corrected upon analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with following code. I hope it will be helpful for you and please use CamelCase Notation for Class Name.

```
public class Userlogin extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

        LoginButton btnFacebookLogin;
        CallbackManager callbackManager;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            setUI();
        }

        private void setUI() {


            btnFacebookLogin = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.btnFacebookLogin);

            btnFacebookLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnFacebookLogin.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile");

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {

                case R.id.btnFacebookLogin:
                    facebookLogin();
            }
        }

        private void facebookLogin() {
    // Callback registration
            btnFacebookLogin.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    // App code

                    final AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                    GraphRequestAsyncTask request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                            username = (user.optString("name"));
                        }
                    }).executeAsync();


                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Success with facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(Userlogin .this, AlertsandPlanning.class));


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // App code
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    // App code
                }
            });

        }


        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
```

Comment: So far I tried the above code and got an error:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.bluejohnson.partymagic.UserLogin.setUI(UserLogin.java:39)
                      at com.example.bluejohnson.partymagic.UserLogin.onCreate(UserLogin.java:31)

Comment: Have you add Facebook dependency in build.gradle file and remove username = (user.optString("name"));

Comment: I think you are setting other Layout to your activity, not the one that you created for this activity, you should set the one correctly.